# Yii2: how to return JSON using $dataprovider

Tags: json, yii2

I have this code

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new DraftSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


    return $this->render('index', [

                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

i want to return $dataprovider in JSON format please any idea on how to do this in Yii2 thanks

Comment: You mean you want to return models in json format ?

Comment: yes i want to return model in json format, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you need   `\Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON`

If you need the return values in json you should use

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    $searchModel = new DraftSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Or, if you need the dataProvider  in render you can try json_encode

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $searchModel = new DraftSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $myJsonDataProvider  json_encode($dataProvider);

    return $this->render('index', [

                'dataProvider' => $myJsonDataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: thanks this help, but how do i access the data in my view file, i can echo it and get json formatted data but when i try to assign this data to javascript variable it won't work

Comment: In the view you have a var $dataProvider  that containt what you have send by the render function ..  .but  your comment seems another question ... so please rate my answer  if is right..  then  if you have question about how accessing view post a proper question about this argument and eventully comment me the new link .. ..